# How can I enable Hidden Surface Removal in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I started learning WebGL. then, I have made a demo.
However, It seems, 'gl.DEPTH_TEST' isnt working.

Here is the demo.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1236764/temp/stackoverflow_20130713/index.html

How can I enable Hidden Surface Removal?
I was wondering If anyone could give me some hints.

Answer (score 1):

```
var near = 0;
var far = 100;
mat4.perspective( projectionMatrix, fov, aspect, near, far );
```

You have specified a near-plane of 0. Due to the way depth buffer values are computed, this causes the depth buffer to be completely useless.

You should set `near` greater than zero. The farther away you set the near plane, the better the depth buffer will function.

The best setting, therefore, is just in front of the closest thing in the scene — in your case, that would be the length of the `eye` vector minus the radius of a bounding sphere for the teapot. But for simple programs, just setting a reasonably-scaled number like 0.1 or 1 is often good enough.

Comment: Thank you so much. The probrem was resolved thanks to your advice!  
I have not known, Near clipping effect on depth buffer.

Comment: Kevin, why should that be so? I thought near and far values are on the Z axis, so negative values should be ok (as long as the camera position is still farther away). Wrong idea?

Comment: @virtualnobi These near and far values are on the Z axis, yes, but we're defining the *projection* matrix, so it's the Z axis relative to the camera position, and there is no view transform involved. Near = 0 is at the camera, and near < 0 is *behind* the camera, by definition. Near < 0 is the region where, if it weren't clipped away, anything drawn would be inverted because it's gone *past* the infinitely-close-thus-infinitely-big point of the camera location.